# Double tap with custom time

Tags: android

I need to implement a custom double tap with time. Example: set to 500ms, 300ms and 700ms. I did not find how to configure it! The problem is to treat it in a class of a Gesture, see:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(View v, MotionEvent e) throws InterruptedException {


    Button  button_now = activity.getButtonByPosition(e.getRawX(), e.getRawY());
    Date d = new Date(); 
    long now = d.getTime();                 


    if(e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            if(button_now != null){                 

                if(button_last != null){                        

                    if(button_now.getId() == button_last.getId())){


                        if(now < lastTouchedTime + DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY){
                            Log.d(tag,"Double tap");
                        }                           
                        else {
                            Log.d(tag,"Single Tap A");
                        }                           
                    }else{
                        Log.d(tag,"Single Tap B");

                    }
                }else{
                    Log.d(tag,"Single Tap C");                      
                }
            }               
            lastTouchedTime = now;
            button_last = button_now;                           
    }       
    return true;
}
```

The problem is: When you double-tap is running, there is also "Single Tap A" before. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am reporting an example of mine that distinuishes from long tap and single tap

```
private boolean DRAGGING;
private boolean ISRELEASED;
private boolean LONGPRESSED;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
static private final int LONG_PRESS_THRESHOLD = 500; //ms

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int eventaction = event.getAction();
    switch (eventaction) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: // touch drag
        // Log.v(TAG,"dragging");
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(checkLongPress);

        DRAGGING = true;

        start_drag_x = (int) event.getRawX();
        start_drag_y = (int) event.getRawY();

        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
        ISRELEASED = false;
        mHandler.postDelayed(checkLongPress, LONG_PRESS_THRESHOLD);

        DRAGGING = false;

        start_drag_x = (int) event.getRawX();
        start_drag_y = (int) event.getRawY();

        break;
    }

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        ISRELEASED = true;
        mHandler.removeCallbacks(checkLongPress);
        if ((!LONGPRESSED) && (!DRAGGING))
            onTouchedCard();
        LONGPRESSED = false;

        if (DRAGGING) {
            // reposition of card view
            //onDraggedCard();
            DRAGGING = false;
        }
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
public void onTouchedCard() {
//Do stuff for single tap
}
public void onLongTouchedCard(){
//Do stuff for long tap
}
private Runnable checkLongPress = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    if (!ISRELEASED) {
        onLongTouchedCard(); //Do stuff for long tap
        LONGPRESSED = true;
    } else
        onTouchedCard();
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When every tap is done you have to check if it was done any tap earlier. To do this for every tap, start a timer which duration is the interval of time in which the user can make the double tap(300 , 500 , 700 ms). So for every tap check if the timer is running; if so call the double tap method, otherwise start the timer. When the timer ends, call the single tap event. You can manage timers with the the structure http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a design issue.

A double tap is two single tabs with a short defined delay between each other.
So before a double tap a single tap will always occur.

You should ask yourself if you really want different events for single and double tapping.
If so, you can only throw a single tap event, when you wait DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY after a tap.
DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY is the maximum delay between two taps that should be handled as double tap.
The problem with this design is, that users will tap and for DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY nothing happens. If DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY is 700ms, people will experience your application as very slow.

If you don't care about this, you can implement this like described by Sanandrea.
Create a Handler and a Runnable.
Inside the runnable you execute your single tab code.
If a user taps, you call this

```
myHandler.removeCallbacks(singleTapRunnable);
if(now < lastTouchedTime + DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY)
    callDoubleTap();
else 
    myHandler.postDelayed(singleTapRunnable, DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY);
lastTouchedTime = now;
```

There is also another opportunity, if you don't want your users to wait DOUBLE_TAP_DELAY before the app responds to your single tap.

You can execute your single tap code directly after the first tap, but reverse this code if you recongnize a double tap.
But this is not possible in all cases and could look strange if view transformations are included in your single tab code.